# Symfony: stoping post validation if normal validation fails

Tags: php, validation, symfony1

Is there a way to prevent a form from proceeding to the post-validation if an error occured in the "normal" validation?

Comment: whats the "normal" validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a callback to validate the form...  For example:

```php
public function configure()
{
  $this->widgetSchema['email'] = new sfWidgetFormInput();
  $this->validatorSchema['email'] = new sfValidatorEmail(array('required' => true));

  $this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(
     new sfValidatorCallback(array('callback' => array($this, 'postValidate')))
  );
}

public function postValidate($validator, $values)       
{
  // only run the post validator if the email has passed validation
  // if it hasn't passed validation, it will be blank and we can skip this
  if ($values['email'])
  {
    $v = new myPostValidator();
    $v->clean($values);
  }

  return $values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean with "normal" and post-validation:

In the action classes you can use the condition:

```
if ($form->isValid()) { // code here before and after the save(); }
```

Or do you use a postExecute in the action?

Comment: the "normal" validators are the validators attached to each widget, and the post-validators are the validators set with setPostValidator()